# passing multiple datatypes into dynamic sql-values not passing in parameterized query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, parameterized-query

I have a dynamic SQL query inside a stored procedure that works and gives me the correct results. But it is taking too long-because I have to compare as varchar instead of int. I believe @query variable in SQL server requires the statement to be a unicode.
Here is the dynamic sql part

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetRows]( @Id varchar(64))
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @Query nvarchar(4000),
 @Comp varchar(256)

SELECT @Comp
=  STUFF(( 
        SELECT DISTINCT ',' + char(39)+
        tci.Component +char(39)
        FROM  TCI tci WITH(NOLOCK) 
            JOIN CDetail cd WITH(NOLOCK) 
           ON  tci.ParentCId = cd.CIdentifier 
            WHERE tci.ParentCId  = @Id
            AND cd.ParentBranch IS NULL
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
    SET @Query
    = 'WITH CTE AS 
        (       
            SELECT '+@Id+' as ParentCId, CIdentifier as ChildCId,
            a.Comp as Comp 
            from dbo.CD cd WITH(NOLOCK)             

               INNER JOIN  

            (SELECT DISTINCT ChildCId,Comp 
            FROM TCI tc WITH(NOLOCK) 
            WHERE ParentCId = '+ @Id + '

                                ) a 
            ON cd.CIdentifier= a.ChildCId
        );
       EXEC (@Query)
        END;
```

Here is the comparison-
        SELECT CIdentifier FROM  #tempTable temp WITH(NOLOCK) 
            WHERE  temp.CIdentifier < '+@Id+'....

This compares as CIdentifier =1122233 instead of CIdentifier ='1122233' because dynamic SQL is not allowing me to pass it as an int. I keep getting the 'cannot convert varchar to int error'

So I used parameterized query - hoping that would enable me to pass int values.Here is the query part

```
        SET @Query
    = N';WITH CTE AS 
        (       
            ......
             (SELECT DISTINCT ChildCId,Comp 
                    FROM TCI tc WITH(NOLOCK) 
                    WHERE ParentCId = @Id
                    AND ChildCId + tc.Comp
                        NOT IN
            (SELECT ChildId + Comp FROM dbo.TCI WITH(NOLOCK) 
        WHERE ParentId IN   (SELECT CIdentifier FROM  #tempTable WITH(NOLOCK) 
                            WHERE  temp.CIdentifier < @Idn
                            AND Comp IN ( @Comp))                   
                            )
                            ) 
            )a 
         ON cd.CIdentifier= a.ChildId
        )
        SELECT * FROM CTE;'


EXEC sp_executeSQL @Query,'@Id VARCHAR(64),@Idn INT,@comp VARCHAR(256)',@Id=@Id,@Idn=@Idn,@comp =@comp
```

This gives me incorrect results and when I saw the execution using a trace - saw that values are not being passed onto the query. How can I get the query to pick up the variables?

Comment: Where, exactly, in the query are you talking about when you say this:   `because I have to compare as varchar instead of int`?

Comment: @TabAlleman: I have edited the question to include the specific part

Comment: What are `@Idn` and `@Comp`? They don't appear to be passed in? I notice in the original query that the data is replicated in the two sections, so I suspect that the second query is not actually the query you are running... or something.

Comment: If `CIdentifier` is a varchar field with non-numeric values, you will get this error.  When you say "This compares as CIdentifier =1122233 instead of CIdentifier ='1122233'", the first comparison is comparing with an int, not a varchar as the second compares with. If you need a varchar compare, make the code segment `WHERE temp.CIdentifier < '''+@Id+'''....` This embeds single quotes into the SQL to be executed.

Comment: @LaughingVergil : yes I thought so too but my CIdentifier column only has numeric values. (Also did the convert using a case for handling the non numeric values- but was still receiving the error).                           I have already tried adding the quotes explicitly(using quotename and your suggestion.I still receive the "Error converting datatypes". Also I am trying to get away from too many quotes into a dynamic tsql- thats why I am curious about the parameterized query –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `WHERE ParentCId = '+ @Id + '` to `WHERE ParentCId = '+ cast(@Id as varchar(16)) + '` in the first query. The problem is SQL Server see's `+` as addition when the value is a `numeric` type, or `date`, and concatenation when it isn't. This is where you get the error from. However, when you do this, it will not make SQL Server compare it as a string literal so you don't have to worry about that. You can see this if you use `PRINT (@Query)` at the end instead of `EXEC (@Query)`

Note, this needs to be changed at the other locations you have any `NUMERIC` data type, like in the `SELECT` portion, `SELECT '+ cast(@Id as varchar(16)) +'`

Also, you code doesn't show where `@Id` value comes from, so be cautious of SQL injection here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanation- it answered a major doubt for me. I was not sure if converting int to string was what I wanted. So casting int as varchar will make it compare as varchar? Am i missing something here?....                               Also I included the variable declarations. Would it be possible for you to let me know why parameters are not being passed?

Comment: No, casting it to varchar in dynamic sql wouldn't cause it to compare as varchar. If you do this, and then run print(@Query) you will see that the query you are executing will have `WHERE ParentCId = 123456`, **not** `WHERE ParentCId = '123456'`. You'd have to explicitly add these quotes in the dynamic string to make this happen.